# Getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Tables[]' to 'Generic.List<>'

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

A few years ago I wrote a WCF service, which runs on a Windows 2003 server under IIS.  I wrote it using VS 2008, and .NET 3.5.  The code in question is this:

```
public static List<ASILookupTables> GetLookupTableAux(bool UseProduction)
{
ASIClassesDataContext dcASI = new ASIClassesDataContext();

var result = from lookups in dcASI.ASILookupTables4s
                         orderby lookups.SortOrder
                         select lookups;

List<ASILookupTables> list = new List<ASILookupTables>();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    ASILookupTables alt = new ASILookupTables();
    //more lines to add other elements
    list.Add(alt);
}

return list;
}
```

Now I'm writing a VS 2010 app, using .NET 4.0, to consume this.  The code snippet in question in the VS 2010 app is this:

```
            LookupSvc.LookupsClient proxy = new LookupSvc.LookupsClient();

        //retrieve list of lookup tables
        List<LookupSvc.ASILookupTables> lookupTables = proxy.GetLookupTableAux(true);
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

"Cannot implicitiy convert type 'AsiEF.LookupSvc.ASILookupTables[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

I don't get it; in the WCF code it looks to me like I'm returning a list. It doesn't look like I'm returning an array.  Is it because the WCF service is in .NET 3.5 and my new project is in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change in the service reference settings if you want the proxy to use `List<T>` or `T[]`.

To change the settings, right click the service reference in the project in solution explorer.  Pick "Configure Service Reference". In "Collection type" pick `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Comment: I've got a follow-up question for you. I'm in the "Service Reference Settings" dialog box, and now see the Collection Type that you were referring to.  It is set to System.Array and I could set it to System.Collections.Generic.List, as you suggest.  I'm wondering, should I check the Always generate message contracts check box, too?

Comment: @Rod, normally no. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are a legend!! Thank you so much for this, already given u +1 + thanks to Rod for posting the original question +1 as well. :)